# Tap to Pay Entitlement issue with stripe terminal

Tags: swift, xcode, stripe-payments, tap-to-pay

**Apples new Tap to Pay integration**

I am receiving an entitlement error from stripe terminal SDK when integrating Tap to Pay from apple in the info.plist.

Im hoping that someone can give me their input on my error output rather than diving into the stripe sdk to point me in the right direction of something I may have missed with entitlements.

I have been approved for tap to pay entitlement and am following the instructions here from apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/proximityreader/setting-up-the-entitlement-for-tap-to-pay-on-iphone

```
<key>com.apple.developer.proximity-reader.payment.acceptance</key>
<true/>
```

[image]

```
import StripeTerminal

func discoverReadersAction() {
            let config = DiscoveryConfiguration(
                discoveryMethod: .localMobile,
              simulated: false
            )

            self.discoverCancelable = Terminal.shared.discoverReaders(config, delegate: self) { error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("discoverReaders failed: \(error)")
                } else {
                    print("discoverReaders succeeded")
                }
            }
        }
```

**error output:**

> discoverReaders failed: Error Domain=com.stripe-terminal Code=2900
> "Operation not permitted. Verify the app has the necessary
> entitlements and that the application bundle is valid."
> UserInfo={com.stripe-terminal:ReaderMessage=Error usually caused by an
> entitlement issue, an invalid application bundle, a configuration
> issue, or a token issue., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation not
> permitted. Verify the app has the necessary entitlements and that the
> application bundle is valid., com.stripe-terminal:Message=Operation
> not permitted. Verify the app has the necessary entitlements and that
> the application bundle is valid.}

**Stripe documentation of Error code:**

> SCPErrorCommandNotAllowed = 2900,
> /**
> The mobile device on which the app is running is in an unsupported
> configuration. Verify that the device is running a supported version of
> iOS and that the mobile device has the capability you are attempting to use.
> */

Stripe terminal documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments/connect-reader?reader-type=tap-to-pay-on-iphone#supported-devices

Comment: What device are you testing to test on and what iOS version?

Comment: ios 11 pro 16.1. The device is confirmed compatible and tested with tap to pay. @DávidPásztor

Comment: A cautionary tale: you can have the entitlement set up correctly in your App ID and your in Provisioning Profile, and it will be listed in the summary of your Provisioning Profile (as you show above) AND yet ... if you don't correctly set the name of your app's entitlements file in the property "Code Signing Entitlements" in Build Settings, and add the property "com.apple.developer.proximity-reader.payment.acceptance" (as you also show above) to your entitlements file, you will still receive this error.

Comment: I am starting now integrating Stripe SDK for tap to pay feature.@adalovelacy,can you let me know did you also used ProximityReader related code for reading cards.Or only Stripe SDK is needed.I am little confused in both SDKs.

Comment: were you able to run your app while in development on your physical device ? if so how ?

Comment: @AhmedEid Stripe has completely updated their SDK since this post and have completely new documentation. Follow Stripes documentation on their website it shows step by step process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try again with the latest Stripe terminal iOS SDK. If the problem still remains, reach out to the Stripe support team at https://support.stripe.com/contact/email